# Wrong Results for Matrix Diagonalization

Tags: fortran

I try and diagonalize the matrix:

[image]

In my analysis, I set $\hbar = 1$. The code is:

```
    MODULE FUNCTION_CONTAINER
    IMPLICIT NONE
    SAVE

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DBL = SELECTED_REAL_KIND(P = 15,R = 200)

    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), PARAMETER :: IMU = (0.0D0, 1.0D0)

    REAL(KIND = DBL), PARAMETER :: S = 1.0D0

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: TEMP1 =  NINT((2.0D0 * S) + 1.0D0)

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DIMJ = TEMP1

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: TEMP2 =  TEMP1*TEMP1

    INTEGER, PARAMETER :: DIMMAT = TEMP2

    CONTAINS

    INTEGER FUNCTION KRONDELTAR(K,L)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    REAL(KIND = DBL), INTENT(IN)::K,L
    REAL(KIND = DBL) :: TEMP
    TEMP = DABS(K - L)
    IF (TEMP < 0.000001D0) THEN
    KRONDELTAR = 1
    ELSE
    KRONDELTAR = 0
    END IF
    END FUNCTION KRONDELTAR

    SUBROUTINE MATJplus(MATOUT)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::MATOUT
    INTEGER::K,L
    REAL(KIND = DBL)::M,MP
    DO K = 1,DIMJ
    DO L = 1,DIMJ
    MP = (S + 1.0D0) - L
    M = (S + 1.0D0) - K
    MATOUT(K,L) = DSQRT(S * (S + 1.0D0) - M * (M + 1.0D0)) * KRONDELTAR(MP,M   + 1)
   END DO
   END DO
   END SUBROUTINE MATJplus

  SUBROUTINE MATJminus(MATOUT)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::MATOUT
  INTEGER::K,L
  REAL(KIND = DBL)::MP,M
  DO K = 1,DIMJ
  DO L = 1,DIMJ
  MP = (S + 1) - L
  M = (S + 1) - K
  MATOUT(K,L) = DSQRT(S* (S + 1.0D0) - M * (M - 1.0D0)) * KRONDELTAR(MP,M - 1)
  END DO
  END DO
  END SUBROUTINE MATJminus

  SUBROUTINE MATJy(MATOUT)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::MATOUT
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ)::Jp,Jm
  CALL MATJplus(Jp)
  CALL MATJminus(Jm)
  MATOUT = (Jp - Jm)/(2.0D0 * IMU)
  END SUBROUTINE MATJy


  SUBROUTINE DIAGONALIZEJy(EIGENSTATESJy,EIGENVALUESJY)
  IMPLICIT NONE
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::EIGENSTATESJy
  REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::EIGENVALUESJY
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ)::JyTEMP,Jy
  COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(2*DIMJ)::D1
  REAL(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(3*DIMJ - 2)::D2
  INTEGER::D3
  CALL MATJy(Jy)
  JyTEMP = Jy
  CALL ZHEEV('V','U',DIMJ,JyTEMP,DIMJ,EIGENVALUESJy,D1,2*DIMJ,D2,D3)
  EIGENSTATESJy = JyTEMP
  END SUBROUTINE DIAGONALIZEJy

  END MODULE FUNCTION_CONTAINER


    PROGRAM TEST
    USE FUNCTION_CONTAINER

    IMPLICIT NONE

    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ) :: EIGENSTATESJy, MatrixJy
  REAL(KIND = DBL), DIMENSION(DIMJ) :: EIGENVALUESJy

    CALL DIAGONALIZEJy(EIGENSTATESJy,EIGENVALUESJY)

    CALL MATJy(MatrixJy)


    OPEN(1, FILE = 'EIGENVALUESJy.DAT')

    OPEN(2, FILE = 'EIGENSTATESJyREAL.DAT')

    OPEN(3,FILE = 'EIGENSTATESJyCOMPLEX.DAT')

    WRITE (1,*) EIGENVALUESJy
    WRITE (2,*) REAL(EIGENSTATESJy)
    WRITE (3,*) AIMAG(EIGENSTATESJy)

  CLOSE(1)

    CLOSE(2)

    CLOSE(3)

  END PROGRAM TEST
```

Up till the subroutine `DIAGONALIZEJy,` I am simply constructing the matrix stated above. One can easily check Fortran constructs is neatly by simply writing the result from the subroutine `MatJy.` I transfer the data to *Mathematica.* The results are:

```
 {{-1., -9.19403*10^-17, 1.}}
```

This is the list of eigenvalues. The list of eigenvectors is:

```
 {{-0.5 + 0. I, 0. - 0.707107 I, 0.5 + 0. I}, {0.707107 + 0. I, 
  0. + 1.04083*10^-16 I, 0.707107 + 0. I}, {-0.5 + 0. I, 
   0. + 0.707107 I, 0.5 + 0. I}}
```

The first eigenvector corresponds to the first eigenvalue (at least that's what I get by printing the column vectors from `EigenvectorsJy` one by one).

Clearly, the result is wrong. See:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=9aa01caf50c9307e9dabe159c9068c41

I hope the link shows the results for the eigenvalues problem done using a widget. The eigenvalues are correct but all the eigenvectors are way off.

Also, when I run only the subroutine that diagonlizes the matrix in my main program which contains a whole host of other stuff, the results are:

```
 {{0.885212, 0., -0.920222}}
```

and

```
 {{0.0439691 + 0. I, -0.388918 + 0. I, 0.5 + 0. I}, {0.707107 + 0. I, 
  0. + 1.04083*10^-16 I, 0.707107 + 0. I}, {-0.5 + 0. I, 
   0. + 0.707107 I, 0.5 + 0. I}}
```

As you can see, the non zero eigenvalues are a bit off and the eigenvectors are too (and still incorrect). Why is the main program giving a different result, perhaphs exacerbating the error? Also, in the first place (minimal example, see above), why am I getting wrong answers?

---

**Edit:** Apparently, the link doesn't show the results so here's a snippet:

[image]

Comment: Where is `ZHEEV` defined? The `save` statement is redundant as modules automatically inherit this attribute. Also, words spelled with all lowercase tend to be more legible than those spelled in uppercase. There is little chance of confusing the letter `i` with the numeral `1,` the letter `B` with the numeral `8`, etc., which can be a problem with some fonts.  Lastly, write code in free source form. This is much more compatible with modern interactive input devices and reduces the possibility of text exceeding the 72 character limit, which could lead the compiler to misinterpret names.

Comment: @jlokimlin  I don't have to define ZHEEV. I'm using the linear algebra library LLAPACK when k compile the code, so the library knows what to do with this command. The original code was written in fixed form so that's why you see capitalized letters; I'm compiling it using the free form .f90 extension though. All right, assume everything is in lower case. Errors?

Answer (score 0):

In short, your `Jy` matrix in the code seems to be the complex conjugate of what is desired (i.e., the image posted in the Question), which results in the eigenvectors that are complex conjugate of the correct ones.

The above error seems to originate from the OP's assumption that list-directed output (as `write(*,*) A`) prints the matrix elements in the "row-major" order, while in fact they are printed in the "column-major" order (see the comments below). By noting this and correcting the program accordingly, I think the program will work as expected.

---

More specifically, adding the following utility routine to print a matrix

```
  subroutine printmat( msg, mat )
      implicit none
      character(*), intent(in) :: msg
      complex(DBL), intent(in) :: mat( dimJ, dimJ )
      integer i1, i2
      print *
      print *, msg
      do i1 = 1, dimJ
          print "(3('(',f10.6,',',f10.6,' ) '))", ( mat( i1, i2 ), i2 = 1,dimJ )
      enddo
  end subroutine
```

and checking the value of `Jp`, `Jm`, `Jy` in the subroutine `MATJy()`

```
 Jp:
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

 Jm:
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

 Jy * sqrt(2):
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000, -1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  1.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000, -1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

eigenvaluesJy(1) =  -1.000000
   eigvec:
    ( -0.500000,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000, -0.707107 )
    (  0.500000,  0.000000 )
eigenvaluesJy(2) =  -0.000000
   eigvec:
    (  0.707107,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000,  0.000000 )
    (  0.707107,  0.000000 )
eigenvaluesJy(3) =   1.000000
   eigvec:
    ( -0.500000,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000,  0.707107 )
    (  0.500000,  0.000000 )
```

we see that the above `Jy` matrix is the complex conjugate of the desired matrix (given as an image in the Question). The reason seems to be that the `Jp` and `Jm` matrices are given as the transpose of the correct ones (according to some pages like [this](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node247.html) and [this](http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node273.html#derive:L1op)). For example, if we change their index as

```
    SUBROUTINE MATJplus(MATOUT)
    IMPLICIT NONE
    COMPLEX(KIND = DBL),DIMENSION(DIMJ,DIMJ),INTENT(OUT)::MATOUT
    INTEGER::K,L
    REAL(KIND = DBL)::M,MP

    DO K = 1,DIMJ
    DO L = 1,DIMJ
    MP = (S + 1.0D0) - L     !! 1, 0, -1  ("m_prime")
    M = (S + 1.0D0) - K      !! 1, 0, -1  ("m")

    !>>> Here, we swap the indices K and L in the LHS
    !!  MATOUT(K,L) = DSQRT(S * (S + 1.0D0) - M * (M + 1.0D0)) * KRONDELTAR(MP, M + 1)
        MATOUT(L,K) = DSQRT(S * (S + 1.0D0) - M * (M + 1.0D0)) * KRONDELTAR(MP, M + 1)

   END DO
   END DO 
   call printmat( "Jplus:", matout )
   END SUBROUTINE
```

(and modifying `MATJminus()` similarly), we obtain the expected result:

```
 Jp:
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

 Jm:
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  1.414214,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

 Jy * sqrt(2):
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000, -1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000, -1.000000 ) 
(  0.000000,  0.000000 ) (  0.000000,  1.000000 ) (  0.000000,  0.000000 ) 

eigenvaluesJy(1) =  -1.000000
   eigvec:
    ( -0.500000,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000,  0.707107 )
    (  0.500000,  0.000000 )
eigenvaluesJy(2) =  -0.000000
   eigvec:
    (  0.707107,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000, -0.000000 )
    (  0.707107,  0.000000 )
eigenvaluesJy(3) =   1.000000
   eigvec:
    ( -0.500000,  0.000000 )
    (  0.000000, -0.707107 )
    (  0.500000,  0.000000 )
```

---

For convenience, here are some matrices taken from the above pages (which can be compared directly with the above `Jp`, `Jm`, `Jy`):

[image: Lxyz]

[image: Lpm]

Comment: When I run my code, I get the following for the matrix Jy: `(  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,-0.70710678118654757     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     , 0.70710678118654757     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,-0.70710678118654757     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     , 0.70710678118654757     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     )`

Comment: Isn't it the same as the image I posted online? I initially thought my Jy matrix isn't being constructed so I changed the indicies M and MP. Could it be the case one thing is being constructed correctly and the other is not; and when I rectify one thing, the other gets messed up? :/

Comment: I seem to be getting the correct results for Jp, Jm and Jy. Actually, that's the thing I "corrected" for earlier.

Comment: By compiling your code on my Mac, it gives the result shown above. I suspect the difference might be due to the way we print the matrix. How do you write your double DO loop to print the matrix elements? (possibly, as `print *, MATOUT` using list-directed output ?)

Comment: I don't do anything fancy; I just use `WRITE(*,*) Jplus` etc at the end of the program.

Comment: When I execute the command, I get: `(  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  1.4142135623730951     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  1.4142135623730951     ,  0.0000000000000000     ) (  0.0000000000000000     ,  0.0000000000000000     )`

Comment: AFTER I change the indices K and L in the in MATOUT as suggested above. Clearly, this is Jminus and not Jplus. What's going on?

Comment: If you print the matrix as `write(*,*) Jplus`, the compiler prints out the matrix elements in the order aligned in the computer memory. In the case of Fortran, the array elements are stored in the "column-major" order, which means that `print *, A` prints the elements in the order `A(1,1), A(2,1), A(3,1), A(1,2), A(2,2), A(3,2), A(1,3), A(2,3), A(3,3)` (when dimJ=3). On the screen, the result appears like the transpose of the original A matrix. Could you check if this is related to the difference of outputs?

Comment: All right, I'll do that. What about the second error? When I use the same subroutine as part of a larger program where I am running the code, I get eigenvalues as 0.8 etc (see above). Even if we resolve the issue in the ME, the larger problem still remains? Things are off in the main program!

Comment: I think it is impossible for the reader to find the reason for the second error unless you show the relevant code.